# solving dpkg dependency issues (argos3 simulator)

Tags: xubuntu, dpkg

I'm run this command to unpackage the argos3 simulator package in Ubuntu in Windows10

```
sudo dpkg -i argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta52.deb
```

and I'm getting this error

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of argos3_simulator:i386:
argos3_simulator:i386 depends on gcc (>= 4.2).
argos3_simulator:i386 depends on g++ (>= 4.2).
argos3_simulator:i386 depends on cmake (>= 2.6).
argos3_simulator:i386 depends on freeglut3-dev (>= 2.6.0).
argos3_simulator:i386 depends on qt5-default (>= 5.5.1).
argos3_simulator:i386 depends on libxi-dev.
argos3_simulator:i386 depends on libxmu-dev.
argos3_simulator:i386 depends on libfreeimage-dev (>= 3.15).
argos3_simulator:i386 depends on libfreeimageplus-dev (>= 3.15).
argos3_simulator:i386 depends on liblua5.2-dev.
argos3_simulator:i386 depends on lua5.2.

dpkg: error processing package argos3_simulator:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
argos3_simulator:i386
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong command to install the package.

The `dpkg` command is not a fully-featured package manager. It doesn't automatically install missing dependencies. It simply installs or removes the package that you told it to install or remove...and nothing else. It refuses to work if dependencies are missing. Once you have installed all those dependencies, then dpkg will do exactly what you told it to do.

The `apt` package manager will automagically install dependencies in the correct order, then install the package you want. It will download the correct packages, then instruct dpkg to install them in the correct order. Apt is *wonderful*.

Try `sudo apt install ./argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta52.deb`